# CodeSandbox issue on production build

Tags: html, reactjs, server, routes, codesandbox

I have taken pull from https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client
and for testing I have created production build with "yarn build".
But i am having issue while uploading it on server.
it redirects to 404 when i try to open any route.
it is running fine with "npm start" on my local machine.
but when i upload its build on server, routes are not accessable.
[here you can see, when i uploaded its build to xampp, it shows 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkcdT.png)